# Access programmatically generated CustomView objects by their ids

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, custom-view

I am trying to access an object of a custom `View` created in `button1` from `button2` this way:

```
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generate);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        ObjectView object = new ObjectView(getApplicationContext());
        object.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        object.setId(componentsIds);
        relativeLayout.addView(object);

    }
});

final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.useComponent);
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       ObjectView object =  findViewById(componentsIds);
       object.bringToFront();
    }
});
```

But I get this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to
>   startup.project.views.ObjectView

Comment: Do you have customview in  your xml layout?

Comment: @VaikundamRaghul No, all properties assigned by code and they get generated dynamically from events like (button click)

Comment: Please add your `ObjectView`. Is it extending from `Button`?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman ObjectView extends from View. its a bitmap shape on a canvas>

Comment: Try using `relativeLayout.findViewById(componentsIds);` inside `onClick`

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman That worked! thanks, you might want to add that below as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the custom view to relativeLayout. So, you have to use `relativeLayout` to get that custom view.

Try using

```
ObjectView object =  relativeLayout.findViewById(componentsIds);
```

Instead of

```
ObjectView object =  findViewById(componentsIds);
```